# How to set someone into spectator mode on Xbox One?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to go into spectator mode but I can't figure out how. When I go into the menu I can only set my gamemode to Survival, Creative, Adventure, or default. I've tried using

```
/gamemode spectator
```

and

```
/gamemode sp
```

but I just get a syntax error at "/gamemode >>spectator<<"

Comment: Why do you keep insisting on adding the [tag:xbox-one] and [tag:minecraft-console] tags to the question?  [tag:Xbox-one] is irrelevant as the answer to the question would be exactly the same if you were playing Minecraft Bedrock Edition on a different system., and [tag:minecraft-console] refers to a different edition of minecraft that has no commands, meaning you couldn't possibly be playing it, so that neither tag beiongs.

Comment: Why do you care so much? The question has an accepted answer and was asked a week ago and was answered with the tags that I added (besides xbox one). Just let it be.

Comment: I care so much about this because the tags are plain\ly not relevant to the question. And no, I will not just "let this be"; it is a clearly mistagged question, which is something that should be fixed, not allowed to stay mistagged indefinitely. I have a firm beleif that questions should be treated identically, regardless of their answered status and age.

Comment: You've still completely failed to provide an explanation as to why clearly irrelevant and/or incorrect tags belong on the question. Niether "it is an old question" nor "it has an accepted answer" are valid reasons; I retag old questions with accepted answers all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/gamemode) there is no gamemode spectator command for Bedrock edition, but I would try `/gamemode 3` just to be sure that the integer values also don't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_unused_features),

> Spectator mode was added in an unknown version, but it cannot be entered by using command and world settings. It can only be entered by using NBT Editor, it also cannot take the view of entities.